# knife bootstrap silent fail on windows 2008 x86

Tags: ruby, windows, x86, chef-infra, winrm

I use knife bootstrap on windows 2008 x86 server is silent fail.
It created windows batch file, but the batch file not executed and return code is 0.

the version info is

> knife-windows version:1.4.1
>   winrm version:1.8.1

and after digging, I think found that.  on knife-windows source code lib/chef/knife/winrm_session.rb "relay_command" method

```
remote_id = @winrm_session.open_shell
command_id = @winrm_session.run_command(remote_id, command)
```

=> it's not run batch file. just exit code is 0, and run other command is OK

```
@winrm_session.create_executor do |executor|
  executor.run_cmd(cmd) do |stdout, stderr|
     Chef::Log.info(cmdstdout)
     Chef::Log.error(cmdstderr)
  end
end
```

=> it's ok to run batch file. but lt's bad idea because can't get real time log

sound like the it is winrm_session run_command bug. but I'm not sure.
how to fix this?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fixed via https://github.com/chef/knife-windows/pull/389
so when update knife-windows to newest version, It will be OK.